# Maintaing Height according to another Div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, flexboxgrid

```css
.col-6 h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.COL1, .COL2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<br></br>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-6 COL1'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus conubia ante, congue faucibus ac a non aptent nisi per commodo facilisi id, tempus lacus maecenas tincidunt mus sociosqu elementum ornare eget. Nascetur vestibulum hac tempor integer semper curae tempus etiam massa, platea fusce pellentesque aenean conubia at lectus non penatibus, nibh venenatis himenaeos scelerisque placerat imperdiet dignissim felis. Feugiat fames lectus magna aenean porttitor taciti hendrerit, integer facilisi nibh habitant dignissim sollicitudin aliquam, massa faucibus dictumst maecenas rhoncus sapien.
    </div>
    <div class='col-6 COL2'>
      <h1>ADVERTISE</h1>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus conubia ante, congue faucibus ac a non aptent nisi per commodo facilisi id, tempus lacus maecenas tincidunt mus sociosqu elementum ornare eget. Nascetur vestibulum hac tempor integer semper curae tempus etiam massa, platea fusce pellentesque aenean conubia at lectus non penatibus, nibh venenatis himenaeos scelerisque placerat imperdiet dignissim felis. Feugiat fames lectus magna aenean porttitor taciti hendrerit, integer facilisi nibh habitant dignissim sollicitudin aliquam, massa faucibus dictumst maecenas rhoncus sapien.</div>
      <h1>ADVERTISE</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right Now this HTML is false like this

[image]

But What I want is to make ***Lorem ipsum*** text gets **overflow:scroll** To keep the Height of the **COL2** equal to **COL1** like this

[image]

And if the ***Lorem Ipsum*** text is too **short** not to make an **overflow**, Then it just gets over itself like this

[image]

keeping **ADVERTISE** at the **BOTTOM** as the **Max-Height** the ***Lorem Ipsum*** can reach.

Is that possible using **Bootstrap** or **CSS** without **JS**?

P.S. **COL1** doesn't/can't have a **Fixed-Height**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:absolute` to all child of your COL2 so it will can not make effect to COL2's height.

```css
.col-6 h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.COL1,
.COL2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.COL2 .top-banner {
  top: 0;
}

.COL2 .bottom-banner {
  bottom: 0;
}

.COL2 div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-6 COL1'>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus conubia ante, congue faucibus ac a non aptent nisi per commodo facilisi id, tempus lacus maecenas tincidunt mus sociosqu elementum ornare eget. Nascetur vestibulum hac tempor integer semper
      curae tempus etiam massa, platea fusce pellentesque aenean conubia at lectus non penatibus, nibh venenatis himenaeos scelerisque placerat imperdiet dignissim felis. Feugiat fames lectus magna aenean porttitor taciti hendrerit, integer facilisi nibh
      habitant dignissim sollicitudin aliquam, massa faucibus dictumst maecenas rhoncus sapien.
    </div>
    <div class='col-6 COL2'>
      <h1 class="top-banner">ADVERTISE</h1>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus conubia ante, congue faucibus ac a non aptent nisi per commodo facilisi id, tempus lacus maecenas tincidunt mus sociosqu elementum ornare eget. Nascetur vestibulum hac tempor integer semper
        curae tempus etiam massa, platea fusce pellentesque aenean conubia at lectus non penatibus, nibh venenatis himenaeos scelerisque placerat imperdiet dignissim felis. Feugiat fames lectus magna aenean porttitor taciti hendrerit, integer facilisi
        nibh habitant dignissim sollicitudin aliquam, massa faucibus dictumst maecenas rhoncus sapien.</div>
      <h1 class="bottom-banner">ADVERTISE</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great!

Answer (score 0):

### Use This code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <style type="">
    .col-6 h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.COL1, .COL2 {
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#overflow{
  height: 145px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
section{
  height: 250px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-6 COL1'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus conubia ante, congue faucibus ac a non aptent nisi per commodo facilisi id, tempus lacus maecenas tincidunt mus sociosqu elementum ornare eget. Nascetur vestibulum hac tempor integer semper curae tempus etiam massa, platea fusce pellentesque aenean conubia at lectus non penatibus, nibh venenatis himenaeos scelerisque placerat imperdiet dignissim felis. Feugiat fames lectus magna aenean porttitor taciti hendrerit, integer facilisi nibh habitant dignissim sollicitudin aliquam, massa faucibus dictumst maecenas rhoncus sapien.
      </div>
      <div class='col-6 COL2'>
        <h1>ADVERTISE</h1>
        <div id = overflow>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit risus conubia ante, congue faucibus ac a non aptent nisi per commodo facilisi id, tempus lacus maecenas tincidunt mus sociosqu elementum ornare eget. Nascetur vestibulum hac tempor integer semper curae tempus etiam massa, platea fusce pellentesque aenean conubia at lectus non penatibus, nibh venenatis himenaeos scelerisque placerat imperdiet dignissim felis. Feugiat fames lectus magna aenean porttitor taciti hendrerit, integer facilisi nibh habitant dignissim sollicitudin aliquam, massa faucibus dictumst maecenas rhoncus sapien.</div>
        <h1>ADVERTISE</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>


</body>
</html>
```

I think this will help you....

Comment: Tried it, It gives `COL2` a fixed height, But not equal to `COL1` height

Comment: just copy the code and paste it and then run.... i tested it works well both have same height